# Utilizing Array with RGB

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, rgb-led, array

I am trying to create a sketch that utilizes two arrays, one array to hold five buttons as input, assigned to pins, and another array to hold five musical notes.  I have attached a RGB LEDs with pull-down resistors and attached a 8 ohms resistor speaker.

The code is as followed:

```
 //Pentatonic Piano
 // C D E G A

 #define NOTE_C   262 //HZ
 #define NOTE_D   294 //HZ
 #define NOTE_E   330 //HZ
 #define NOTE_G   392 //HZ
 #define NOTE_A   440 //HZ

 const int SPEAKER = 9;   //speaker on pin 10
 const int BLED = 10;      //Blue LED on pin 9
 const int GLED = 6;      //Green LED on pin 6
 const int RLED = 5;      //Red LED on pin 3

 int buttonState = 0; 

 //Button Array
 int Buttons[]= {11, 8, 7, 4, 3};

 //Tone Note Array
 int Notes[] = {NOTE_C, NOTE_D, NOTE_E, NOTE_G, NOTE_A};

 void setup()
 {
 pinMode(BLED, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(GLED, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(RLED, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(Buttons, INPUT);
 }


 void loop()
 {

   buttonState = digitalRead(Buttons);

   if (buttonState = Buttons[0])
   { tone(SPEAKER, Notes[0]);
    digitalWrite(BLED, LOW);
    digitalWrite(GLED, LOW);
    digitalWrite(RLED, HIGH);

   }
   else if (buttonState = Buttons[1])
   {tone(SPEAKER, Notes[1]);
    digitalWrite(BLED, LOW);
    digitalWrite(GLED, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(RLED, LOW);
   }
   else if (buttonState = Buttons[2])
   {tone(SPEAKER, Notes[2]);
    digitalWrite(BLED, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(GLED, LOW);
    digitalWrite(RLED, LOW);

   }
   else if (buttonState = Buttons[3])
   {tone(SPEAKER, Notes[3]);
    analogWrite(BLED, 127);
    analogWrite(GLED, 0);
    analogWrite(RLED, 127);

   }
   else if (buttonState = Buttons[4])
   {tone(SPEAKER, Notes[4]);
    analogWrite(BLED, 0);
    analogWrite(GLED, 127);
    analogWrite(RLED, 127);

   }

   else
   {
    digitalWrite(BLED, LOW);
    digitalWrite(GLED, LOW);
    digitalWrite(RLED, LOW);
    noTone(SPEAKER);
   }
 }
```

The problem is no matter what button I press, the RGB only emits a green light and there is absolutely no sound coming from the speaker.  I am truly stumped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, these statements:

```
if (buttonState = Buttons[0])
```

are doing an assignment, not a test for equality. You want:

```
if (buttonState == Buttons[0])
//               ^Notice
```

Next, `pinMode` takes two integers, but you are passing an array. You can use a loop to call `pinMode` multiple times:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(Buttons) / sizeof(Buttons[0]); i++) {
     pinMode(Buttons[i], INPUT);
}
```

Same goes for `digitalRead()`. You need to read the state for each button:

```
buttonState = digitalRead(Buttons[0]);
if (buttonState == HIGH) {
   ....
}
buttonState = digitalRead(Buttons[1]);
if (buttonState == HIGH) {
   ....
}
//etc
```